# Marshmallow: why can't I access the fields attributes?

Tags: python, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I have a pretty regular schema class like:

```
class TestSchema(db_schema.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    xxx = fields.Str()
    name = fields.Str(validate=validate.Length(min=1), required=True, error_messages={"required": "The name is required."})
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
        model = TestModel
```

And I would like to analyze the class itself to be able to form some metainformation for the frontend. But I can't access xxx nor name like:

```
schema_instance = TestSchema()
schema_instance.xxx ???AttributeError: 'TestSchema' object has no attribute 'xxx'
```

Comment: You need need another Class and dump that to `TestSchema` and then it will work

Answer (score 2):

As @maruthi-adithya comments, you need to define another class to dump the result of TestSchema; you'll need to make use of `postload` which handles post-deserialization in which you can return the data as you need, check the documentation for it [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.decorators.html#marshmallow.decorators.post_load). Below an example:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, xxx, name, id):
        self.xxx = xxx
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f'<Test(xxx={self.id}, name={self.name})'
        )


class TestSchema(db_schema.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    xxx = fields.Str()
    name = fields.Str(validate=validate.Length(min=1), required=True, error_messages={"required": "The name is required."})
    id = fields.Integer()
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
        model = TestModel

    @postload
    def return_as_object(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Test(**data)
```